# How to implement features for donation in Android application?

Tags: android

Personally I dislike the approach of publishing free/paid application pair. What I like more is a helper "donation" application or donation button and donation id registration inside single application.

Can you point to some tutorials on how to implement this? I would be also glad if you mention pros and contras of these two approaches.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using in-app billing then market will charge 30% for a transaction. While in-app billing requires items to be sold on a fixed price which will give you a little scope if your items are not managed(fixed priced). There is a way to do it from your android app without leaving it.

**Paypal integration for android** becomes fairly simple if you follow their developer site. You will need to download and integrate the library provided by Paypal, which is available on [Paypal developer site](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-payment-libraries).

[Sample Pizza application](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_MPL_Developer_Guide_and_Reference_Android.pdf) built using Eclipse demonstrate how to do actual integration which is quite simple. Although paypal seems forgot to use relative path for library. So you will have to change library path and application is ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html is the official tutorial for the issue.